# JHipster Atmosphere websocket does not connect

Tags: angularjs, websocket, atmosphere, jhipster

With a newly scaffolded app generated from "yo jhipster" and started with "mvn spring-boot:run" and "grunt server" I am able to load the app and do operations like login, view metrics, see sessions, settings, logs, and audits. However, whenever I view the "User Tracker" page I don't see anything?

I believe this section is supposed to demonstrate Atmosphere websocket / AngularJS integration? Looking at the browser console logs, I see the following:

```
Websocket failed. Downgrading to Comet and resending atmosphere.js:2866
GET http://0.0.0.0:9000/websocket/activity?X-Atmosphere-tracking-id=0&X-Atmosph…true&X-Cache-Date=0application%2Fjson&X-atmo-protocol=true&_=1393276976964 404 (Not Found)
```

It appears that a websocket connection is attempted but eventually times out and the fallback long polling doesn't work? I'm using the latest Chrome (also tried on latest versions of Firefox and Safari as well).

Am I missing something simple?

**-- Update 1 --**

Deploying it as a WAR to Tomcat 7.0.50 shows data back from Atmosphere in the User Tracker page but it continuously loops trying to get a WebSocket connection (HTTP status code 101: switching protocols) so the user data appears and disappears periodically. I saw an error in Chrome like this:

```
No suspended connection available. Make sure atmosphere.subscribe has been called and request.onOpen invoked before invoking this method
```

The Tomcat logs show the following:

```
[WARN] org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultAnnotationProcessor - Unable to detect annotations. Application may fail to deploy.
```

**-- Update 2 --**

Deploying it as a WAR to Jetty 8.1.14.v20131031 (Jetty 9.1.1.v20140108 throws errors) and testing it with Chrome 32.0.1700.107 appears to work for the fallback transport of long-polling. The initial connection to WebSockets, however, fails because Atmosphere for some reason thinks the servlet container is Tomcat? In the server logs, it throws the following issue:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request cannot be cast to org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade
    at org.atmosphere.container.TomcatWebSocketUtil.doService(TomcatWebSocketUtil.java:141)
    at org.atmosphere.container.Tomcat7Servlet30SupportWithWebSocket.service(Tomcat7Servlet30SupportWithWebSocket.java:62)
```

Thanks again for all your help -- definitely making progress :)

**-- Update 3 --**

To summarize everything:

1. Currently "mvn spring-boot:run" and "grunt server" don't work together for Websockets or long-polling
2. If you deploy the JHipster WAR (mvn package) to Jetty 8.1.14.v20131031 then it works but you need to remove the following dependency from your JHipster pom.xml or else Atmosphere will not provide WebSocket support:

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
   </dependency>
   ```
3. Argh. False alarm -- I had it running using streaming, not websockets, so WebSockets still has the error from update2

Answer (score 3):

No you're not missing anything :-)

If you use the Java server directly it should work: you need to connect to the application with another browser (or another tab) and you will see working.

However, with "grunt server", there is a bug: the Grunt proxy just does not support Websocket, so it doesn't work... There is one strange thing, thus, it's that the fallback transport does not work.

I'm filling this as a bug.

-- update 1 --

Concerning your update, it looks there's another Atmosphere bug:
http://atmosphere-framework.2306103.n4.nabble.com/Log-warning-that-Atmosphere-is-unable-to-detect-annotations-td4658159.html

It seems that Atmopshere can't find its annotation inside a WAR, can you try the same thing in development mode ("mvn spring-boot:run")? That would means it's an issue with WARs in Tomcat

Comment: Thanks for the fast response! I tried building a WAR (dev mode) and deployed it to Tomcat 7.0.50, which shows data in the User Tracker page but it throws a bunch of errors in Chrome's console (I updated the post above with the errors) so the connection doesn't appear to be too reliable.

Comment: I added -- Update 2-- above. Jetty8 appears to work for the fallback transport of long-polling but the initial WebSocket connection fails because Atmosphere thinks the servlet container is Tomcat for some reason

Comment: Also I tried "mvn spring-boot:run" and it appears to deploy fine but I'm not sure how to access the webapp? I don't see anything at localhost:8080. Previously I had to run "grunt server" and navigate to localhost:9000 to see anything but then I'm back to square one with no websocket or long-polling support.

Comment: Okay, I resolved --Update2-- above so that JHipster + Websockets works on Jetty 8.1.14.v20131031. I followed a discussion on Atmosphere at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/atmosphere-framework/3SZx4CkGBOM and removed spring-boot-starter-tomcat from the JHipster Maven dependencies list b/c Atmosphere was reading Tomcat libs so it incorrectly thought Jetty was Tomcat

Comment: @MinhNguyen
Were you able to get websockets with atmosphere work with jhipster on tomcat? If so, can you please share a sample code and also it would be helpful if you can guide me a little with the configurations that you did.